FastAPI & Authlib external oauth authentication reuse authlib client
I have trouble understanding how the Authlib middleware works with fastAPI.
I have something working, but I don't think it's the right way to do it.
What I would like is to be able to create a client like in this example.
auhlib client.
From what I understand, the SessionMiddleware is supposed to do all the work and with a client that auto refresh the token and all that.
What I do is store the access_token inside request.session and then read it again when I need it, but it looks like the wrong way to do it.
Here's my code :
import requests
from authlib.integrations.base_client import OAuthError
from authlib.integrations.starlette_client import OAuth
from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.requests import Request
from starlette.responses import HTMLResponse, RedirectResponse
from starlette.middleware.sessions import SessionMiddleware

app = FastAPI()
app.add_middleware(SessionMiddleware, secret_key="some-random-string")
oauth = OAuth()
oauth.register(
    name="oauthprovider",
    client_id="MYCLIENTID",
    client_secret="MYCLIENTSECRET",
    server_metadata_url="https://example.com/.well-known/openid-configuration",
)
@app.get('/login')
async def login(request: Request):
    redirect_uri = "http://localhost:8000/auth/callback"
    return await oauth.oauthprovider.authorize_redirect(request, redirect_uri)
@app.get('/auth/callback')
async def auth(request: Request):
    try:
        token = await oauth.oauthprovider.authorize_access_token(request)
    except OAuthError as error:
        return HTMLResponse(f'<h1>{error.error}</h1>')
    user = token.get('userinfo')
    if user:
        request.session['user'] = dict(user)
        request.session['access_token'] = token.get('access_token')
    return RedirectResponse(url='/docs')
@app.get('/fetchexternalAPI')
async def externalAPI(request: Request):
    headers = { "Authorization": f"Bearer {request.session['access_token']}"}
    res = requests.get(url="https://example.com/api", headers=headers)
    return res.json()

I would like to do something like:
oauth.oauthprovider.get("https://example.com"),
so I use the client correctly (depending on the current user obviously) and the token would be refreshed I guess?
The only example I found doesn't use this client... example

You want SessionMiddleware to update Oauth sessions or I am missing something?

Yes, and I would like an http client that uses the token of the session if possible, with the autorefresh of the token when expired.

It kinda not possible to do. You will need to write your own middleware to achieve this or write dependency method. Fastapi session and oauth session are independent from each other.

Ok, thank you for the answer, I’ll have a look !
